# Setting double borders in Raphael with `setAttribute`

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

In this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pgschr/17hscxnL/27/) I have two SVG rects. The first one inside an SVG tag, the second one rendered with Raphael JS. Both rects should be identical with double borders, but they are not. Using `node.setAttribute` in Raphael JS is supposed to set the low level SVG attribute, so this should work. What's missing here?

```
<svg height="100" width="100">
  <rect class="rect2" height="50" width="50" x='25' y='25' />
</svg>

<div id="the_canvas"></div>


.rect2 {
  fill: none;
  outline: 2px double black;
  outline-offset: 0;
}


var w = 100, h = 100;
var paper = Raphael("the_canvas", w, h); 

var rect = paper.rect(25,25,50,50);
rect.node.setAttribute('fill', 'none');
rect.node.setAttribute('outline','2px double black');
rect.node.setAttribute('outline-offset', 0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a Raphael issue, it's the way SVG works.

outline and outline-offset are not mapped SVG attributes. I.e. they do not map to CSS properties. In fact neither of these CSS properties should really do anything in SVG (they aren't mentioned in the SVG specification).

Browsers exist mainly to render HTML, sometimes things that should only work in HTML bleed into SVG when they should have no effect there.

Comment: Thanks. What is your recommendation to have double line borders in Raphael? Just create an additional rect?

Comment: Draw 2 rect elements of slightly different sizes each having a stroke.